# Color street on Android MapView?

Tags: android, google-maps

Is there any possibility to highlight a street using the Google Maps API? I want to set a color on a street, similar as it is done in the navigation function of Google Maps.

If there is no generic implementation for this - and I guess there probably isn't - is there any good/simple solution for this? The only thing I could think of was reverse geocoding coordinates and see if those coordinates resolve to the street I want to color and if they did I would then draw some color on to those points. But this is a really ugly solution. ;-)

I hope some clever genious can help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any possibility to highlight a street using the Google Maps API?

Not the Android one. It may or may not be possible using the Web-based Google Maps -- I am not familiar with what it can all do. If you find the Web-based maps do support this, you can always embed one of those in your app via `WebView`.

> If there is no generic implementation for this - and I guess there probably isn't - is there any good/simple solution for this?

I suspect there is no solution for this, simple or otherwise. Your reverse-geocoding solution would take a very long time, just due to Internet overhead.

Comment: Any idea about how third-party navigation apps do this?

Comment: @crapper: There should be no "third-party navigation apps" for Google Maps on Android, as IMHO that would violate the Maps add-on terms of service (of course, IANAL). To make this work, as you have already determined, you need a bunch of coordinates that represent the street. Given that you have these, highlighting the street is a matter of an `Overlay`. However, there is nothing in Android that will give you this street-coordinate data. Third-party navigation apps presumably have licensed their own street-coordinate data, from wherever, and possibly at substantial cost.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I just stumbled upon My Tracks for Android, which is Open Source and seemingly is highlighting paths. I will have to take a look at that.

Comment: @crapper: AFAIK, it is recording coordinates as you walk, and so it can use that to draw the paths.

Comment: Yes, seems so. My application will also be recording coordinates; I will have to snap those to the nearest street, since it is impossible not to be on a street with my application. I suppose it's best to resolve the coordinates to an address and then resolve them back to coordinates in order to snap them to the street. I just was doubtful if connecting those coordinates will really overlay the street with a good accuracy.

Comment: @crapper: "since it is impossible not to be on a street with my application" -- your application blows up the phone if you leave the street? :-)

Comment: Is this still not possible? So that the MapView kind of matches my company color like the rest of the app (ActionBar, UI elements etc.) does...

Comment: @user754730: If *you* draw on the map (markers, polylines, etc.), you choose the color. Whatever *Google* draws on the map is Google's. Neither offer a way to highlight a street, unless you have a *lot* of points on the street for you to draw your own polyline.